# Spring Boot app throwing InvocationTargetException when /actuator/prometheus is hit

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application which is intermittently throwing a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` when `/actuator/prometheus` is hit.

The missing class is `javax/transaction/TransactionManager`.

I can see from the stack trace that the missing class is `javax/transaction/TransactionManager` which is required in `org.terracotta.statistics.PassThroughStatistic.value(PassThroughStatistic.java:63)`

My current assumption is that Prometheus is trying to collect a statistic that it shouldn't be, hence the error. I have tried searching my classpath for TransactionManager and it's not there.

I'm using

- Spring Boot version 2.1.6.RELEASE
- default application server (Tomcat 9)
- jooq
- NOT using spring-boot-starter-data

Here's the stack trace:

```
Error Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Error Request URI: /actuator/prometheus
person_key: Session: 98BED75FF5146BC71D8D516AA425B5B9

Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.terracotta.statistics.PassThroughStatistic.value(PassThroughStatistic.java:65)
    at net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.AbstractStatistic.value(AbstractStatistic.java:57)
    at net.sf.ehcache.statistics.extended.SemiExpiringStatistic.value(SemiExpiringStatistic.java:33)
    at net.sf.ehcache.statistics.StatisticsGateway.getLocalHeapSizeInBytes(StatisticsGateway.java:320)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.internal.DefaultGauge.value(DefaultGauge.java:40)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$newGauge$3(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:245)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.MicrometerCollector.collect(MicrometerCollector.java:69)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:183)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:216)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:137)
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:22)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.scrape(PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor391.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:278)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:334)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor390.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.utilities.www.tomcat.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.mycompany.restful.RequestDuplicateFilter.doFilter(RequestDuplicateFilter.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.mycompany.utilities.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.mycompany.utilities.ETagFilter.doFilter(ETagFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor187.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.terracotta.statistics.StatisticsManager$MethodCallable.call(StatisticsManager.java:113)
    at org.terracotta.statistics.PassThroughStatistic.value(PassThroughStatistic.java:63)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionManager;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker.getAllFields(ObjectGraphWalker.java:266)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker.getFilteredFields(ObjectGraphWalker.java:229)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker.walk(ObjectGraphWalker.java:160)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(SizeOf.java:72)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.sizeOf(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:190)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore.getInMemorySizeInBytes(MemoryStore.java:802)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.TransactionManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    ... 115 more
```

I expect this endpoint to return a list of metrics, and no exception to be thrown.

Comment: Can you include your pom.xml?

Comment: Any work around on this issue?

Comment: Not yet. I tried including the relevant jar that contains javax.transaction.TransactionManager but that didn't help. Only seems to be an intermittent issue for me so far. Are you also experiencing this problem @zachariahyoung?